# ActiveRecord Associations: Getting data through multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a problem with my Active Record Associations and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I will try the best to explain my problem, but I'm not even sure what to title it.

I have three tables in my database that are all interconnected and I need to call information from each of the three tables within one view file.

There can be multiple posts within a topic, each post (and topic) has one user attached to it. I need to be able to call data in the User table using Post and Topics.

Question: How to get data from a table through multiple Models. (Topic -> Post -> User)

**The Models**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :forum
    has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy  
    belongs_to :user
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :topic  
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics
    has_many :posts, through: => :topics
end
```

In the View/Topics/show.html, I am trying to show the user who posted. When I try to get the information, it is giving me errors of undefined methods for "name". What I want is something like:

http://i44.tinypic.com/1z4kapj.png

Example: Post 1 was created by UserName

**View/Topics/Show.html.erb**

```
<% @topic.posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
        <td class="subforum" width="80%">
            <%= post.created_at %>
            <div class="go-right">
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="row1">
            <%= post.users.name %>
            <%= post.user_id %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="row1">
            <%= post.content %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: By the way, you wrote "The Controllers", but those are the models you posted. I'm assuming that was just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, except that you should be invoking `post.user`, instead of `post.users`.

In your `Post` model, you have a line `belongs_to :user`. This means that the `Post` model has a single `User` object. Meaning, you access the dependent object via the singular form of the association name, in this case simply `.user`. If you use the pluralized form with this kind of relationship, you get back a useless(in this case) collection proxy which, as you've seen, does not behave the same as your object.

If you had something like `has_many :users`, then you would indeed use the pluralized `.users`, and you'd get a collection of `User` objects, in the same was as `Topics.posts` gives you a collection `Post` objects.

**ALSO:**

In this line: `link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)`, ditch the `@` symbol, it should be `link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post)`. Remember that this symbol refers to an instance variable, which is completely different than a local scope variable of the same name (in other words @post != post).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried post.user.name and I ended up with the same error: 

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

I've tried every way i could think of to make it work, and it does not. I have a feeling I am missing something in the model and that is why it is not working.

Comment: @lindsiria ah ha, that last part of the error message makes all the difference. If you're familiar with Java, this is the same as a null pointer exception. It means you got back nothing from that method, and tried to invoke a method on that "nil object". In other words, that particular `Post` object doesn't have an associated `User` object.

Comment: I can understand that, but how would I make it so that the Post object has an associated User object?

Comment: @Lindsiria Can't really answer that as I'd only be guessing how your system works. If a `Post` MUST have a `User`, when the `Post` is created, whichever user created the `Post` should be associated when the `Post` gets saved. That's a completely different topic though, as now we're getting in to forms and model creation. Basic quick answer is you can set an association the same way you set other values, simply `post.user = user_who_created_post`, or `post.user_id = user_id_of_dude_who_created_post`. Again, really depends how this part of your system is set up.

Comment: @Lindsiria Additionally, if you have `Post` objects with `nil` user_id columns in your database, assuming these were created by accident, you might just be better off deleting those from the DB entirely so you can move on. Once you get the `Post` setting the `User` properly, you shouldn't have any further issues with that.

Comment: You are correct. I knew there were null objects in the user_id column, but I hadn't realized that the first post in every thread (when you created the thread), it was always null, meaning there would be an error... Yay more bugs to fix... I feel like an idiot. Lol Thank you :)